# How to print formatted output?

Tags: java

I would like check how to output formmatted output like table

```
123      456    789
123444   4556   789999
```

every cell is aligned. I am wondering if I could get this kind of output using just System.out.print?

Comment: you can use System.out.format("%20d%15d%25d", int1, int2, int3);  to give padding to each different integer. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: You could use `System.out.format`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html

Comment: the default if left padded, how can i change to right padding?

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking if there is a function that allows you to print variables, like an array into that format? If so, the closest thing would be the System.out.format check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html for the proper syntax for it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you could using `\t` (the tab) and a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = { { 123, 456, 789 }, { 123444, 4556, 789999 } };
    for (int[] vals : arr) {
        for (int i : vals) {
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print('\t');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

or using `printf` with formatted output like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = { { 123, 456, 789 }, { 123444, 4556, 789999 } };
    for (int[] vals : arr) {
        for (int i : vals) {
            System.out.printf("%d\t", i);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output is the same

```
123     456     789 
123444  4556    789999
```